# Need Help with PWM Motor Speed Controller Circuit

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, 555

I am using the following circuit to make my PWM Motor Speed controller. I just replaced the MOSFET IRF510 with IRF540 and LM555 with NE555. I found the schematic on the web.

[image]

My motor is 12V rated and draws approx 200mA current when on full speed. But the motor was not receiving the required duration of current to start running. And finally, it didn't work. So, I tried increasing the C2 to 1uF (electrolytic) and it started rotating. Well, but with 1uF, the highest frequency of PWM could rotate it at half of its max speed. I want to increase the speed of the motor. Should I keep increasing the Capacitor? Would it actually destroy the purpose of controlling motor speed with PWM?

What I certainly did not understand is the purpose of R2. What does R2 do? Would the speed of the motor be impacted by changing this resistor value?

Comment: First of all, pins 3 and 7 are reversed (look at the pin descriptions). Make sure Vcc = 12 vdc. R2 will be explained after you correct wiring errors and try again, but is connected to the gate of the mosfet for a reason.

Comment: Yes, that's a severe error which I also noticed in the diagram. But I found this configuration of NE555 based PWM on several blogs on the internet. This somehow convinced me to give it a try. I made the 'Wrong' circuit and somehow got the motors running by increasing the Capacitor. Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope to visualize the PWM output. So, do you confirm that the circuit should remain intact except pin 3 and 7 to be reversed?

Comment: Yes, get pins 3 and 7 corrected before damage occurs. It is not unusual to see errors in schematics, such as transistor/diode polarities wrong, etc. Always check the official manufacture specs and examples for correct wiring of the device.

Comment: Great help Sparky256. Let me give it a try by correcting the pins. I will get back if I still face any issue. Well, would you please help me to understand the need of R2? Do I need that when I swap pin 7 and 3?

Comment: Actually you can use pin 7 as an output which is the discharge transistor O/P (hence the pull up resistor R2 to provide a +V to the gate). Its not a brilliant idea as it can only sink current. I would use the conventional output (pin 3) to drive the MOSFET with a 47R series resistor to reduce any ringing. If you change the silicon diodes for germanium (or more likely schottky types) you can squeeze out a few extra % points on M/S ratio.

Comment: Ok, so with Pin 3 O/P config, I don't need the 10K resistor, just a 47R series resistor between Pin 3 and MOSFET's Ground. And preferably replacement of 1N4001 with 1N4148 or similar would give it a better ratio. Let me try this.
 
If you could explain this - "Its not a brilliant idea as it can only sink current"

Comment: Pin 3 is correct, but should probably also be used as the MOSFET gate driver (R2 unnecessary, pin 7 can be left disconnected). Yes, 47 or 100 ohms in series with the gate is a good idea, as are the 4148s.

Comment: Pin 7 disconnected or at the middle pin of the POT, just where pin 3 is connected right now in the 'wrong' diagram?

Comment: Its from the Internet .It must be good !?

Comment: Your circuit should work fine as shown. However the IRF510 has high Rdson and is only good for a couple of Amps at most. What are the specifications of your motor (esp. stall current or operating current at maximum power)? What is the power source?

Comment: I swapped pin 3 and 7 and it worked like a charm. This I replaced C2 with 0.01uF.
@BruceAbbott did you mean to say the circuit is correct? If so, why didn't I get enough power to rotate the motor? WHat changes are required to increase the Frequency/Amplitude of the PWM? My motor draws approx 200mA Current at full power. I don't have any datasheet of the motor.

Comment: Sorry I just looked at your circuit diagram and forgot you had changed the FET. The IRF540 has better Rdson, but also has high Gate capacitance so R2 should be reduced to 1K if using pin 7 for output. C2 = 0.1uF creates a PWM frequency of ~140Hz which is a bit low (best is >2KHz for normal motors, >20KHz for coreless). 0.01uF should give ~1kHz which is better. However the 1N4001 is too slow at this frequency. You should use eg. 1N4148 (high speed switching diode) for D1 and D2, and 1N5817 (Schottky) across the motor.